# Windows service in svchost vs self-container service

Tags: windows

I plan to install a service but quite confuse what the difference between both as a process in svchost or software.exe.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for a separate exe, but that's just my opinion. It's really entirely up to you. Nothing in regards to functionality, performance, development time etc will be any different.

There's nothing wrong with running it as a service through svchost though. SvcHost was implemented by Microsoft because they want to make the code-base more reusable. The goal is to have the reusable code in dlls instead of smashing it into exe files. But because a dll is not an executable, it can not be started directly. Hence, they made svchost as a runner for it.

Comment: I have create a Java application and has install as a Windows service, trying to start using java -jar file.jar. It won't start. There is no error except service message shown it take too long to response. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

the difference is of the User Name You can run run your application as

**UserName or Administrator**